# PHP csv report add Column names

Tags: php

I want to save data to csv file.

I can already do it but I also want to add like column names so that the report is more readable but this is where I am struggling:

My code so far:

```
<?php
namespace Test\UserBundle\ReportsBuilder;

class RegistrationReport {

    public function buildRegReport($data)
    {
        $cavPath = '../src/Test/UserBundle/Resources/reports/test_report_'.date('Y-m-d H:i:s').'.csv';
        $csvh = fopen($cavPath, 'w+');

            $row = 'rowid'.",".'emailaddress'.",".'firstname'.",".'surname'.",".'contact_number';

        foreach ($data as $value)
        {
            $reportRows = array
            (
                $value['rowid'],
                $value['emailaddress'],
                $value['firstname'],
                $value['surname'],
                $value['contact_number'],
            );
                fputcsv($csvh, $reportRows);
        }
        fclose($csvh);
    }
}
```

So the $data param passed into the method contains array of array. was thinking of creating a string with column names then some how add it to the loop, but I might be wrong with this one any suggestions how i can assign colum names to my report.

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well I don't really get why you create an array within an array loop, including the same fields..

But to answer your question, putting column names into your CSV file is actually really easy. The only thing you need to do is to add the column names in the first line (comma seperated). It's exactly the same as adding an row with data.

Example:

```
    fputcsv($csvh, array_keys($data[0]));
    foreach ($data as $value) {
        fputcsv($csvh, $value);
    }
```

Hope this answers your question.

Comment: WOW lol i followed exacly what you have written, removed array from inside the foreach, and added fputcsv before foreach. Could you explain a bit more what exacly happened pleas I find it a bit wired :P why use fputcsv twice.

Comment: fputcsv formats and inserts a line as CSV. Your foreach loop inserts all data found in the array $data. If you put the line inside the loop, it will add the keys more then 1 time. A CSV contains nothing more then just comma seperated strings. By adding the keys before your foreach loop, your inserting the array keys as first line in the file. This means your file will look like this:

Comment: key1,key2,key3 (this is the first line of your file). After that your loop starts working and will output the following:
value1,value2,value3.

Answer (score 1):

To add your header in csv you can use the same method as adding data.

So you have to change this line

```
$row = 'rowid'.",".'emailaddress'.",".'firstname'.",".'surname'.",".'contact_number';
```

To:

```
fputcsv($csvh, array('rowid', 'emailaddress', 'firstname', 'surname', 'contact_number'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<?php
namespace Test\UserBundle\ReportsBuilder;

class RegistrationReport {

    public function buildRegReport($data)
    {
        $cavPath = '../src/Test/UserBundle/Resources/reports/test_report_'.date('Y-m-d H:i:s').'.csv';
        $csvh = fopen($cavPath, 'w+');

        $row = array('rowid','emailaddress','firstname','surname','contact_number');
        fputcsv($csvh, $row);

        foreach ($data as $value)
        {
            $reportRows = array
            (
                $value['rowid'],
                $value['emailaddress'],
                $value['firstname'],
                $value['surname'],
                $value['contact_number'],
            );
                fputcsv($csvh, $reportRows);
        }
        fclose($csvh);
    }
}
```

Comment: `fputcsv() param two has to be an array, implode returns string`

Comment: No need to implode as delimiter is comma by default. For reference please find this link: http://php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the hear in csv file also like:

```
fputcsv($csvh, $row); before the foreach()
```